# Any reason to believe that $NP \neq P$ is unprovable in ZFC

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, computational-complexity

We know  $NP \neq P$ from a lot of point of view like empirical reason,or theoretical reasons such as finite model theory or descriptive complexity.Although we find so many reasons to believe $NP \neq P$,we have not found any proof for it now.

So any reason to believe that $NP \neq P$ is unprovable in ZFC?Any result about unprovability of  $NP \neq P$ in  ZFC or weaker system than ZFC.

Comment: Decade out of date: Aaronson, Scott. "Is P versus NP formally independent?." *Bulletin of the EATCS* 81 (2003): 109-136. ([PDF download link](http://www.scottaaronson.com/papers/pnp.pdf)). Or better: *[Quantum Computing Since Democritus](http://www.scottaaronson.com/democritus/)*.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke,thank you for the reference.It seems that the critical hard part for a proof is relating bound,usually,problems about bound in math is hard.

Comment: Your spacing is off.  You want not $NP! = P$ but rather $NP\;{!\!=}\;P$ ... or (for mathematicians) even better $NP \ne P$.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar,thank you very much ,I will edit it.